# Pseudo Element (:after) not working in FF/IE, but working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

See this Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wcybk

the button is working in Chrome, but not IE/FF

```
<input name="input_15" id="input_6_15" class="medium" tabindex="8" type="file">
#input_6_15{position:relative;}
#input_6_15:after {
content: "Upload Media";
width: 150px;
height: 20px;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #626D2D;
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding: 8px 5px 10px;
color: #FFF;
visibility: visible;
top: 4px;
left: -38px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
line-height: 26px;
z-index: 99999999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that Firefox and IE have a hard time with rending pseudo elements on inputs (more about it here: [Bug 724369 - :after :before pseudo elements for input elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724369)).

My solution was to use this:
    @-moz-document url-prefix() { //Firefox code here
    }

And target the container div of the input element instead.